# Change inner parts or the text inside a tag

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to replace `second_part` or `third_part` with e.g. `bar`.

```py
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True, remove_blank_text=True)
root = etree.fromstring("<p>first_part<lb/>second_part<lb/>third_part</p>", parser=parser)
```

We can easily get and change first_part:

```py
p.text
# returns 'first_part'
```

Also we can retrieve tail text with tags:

```py
''.join(ET.tostring(e, 'unicode') for e in root)
# returns '<lb />second_part<lb />third_part'
```

But I want to change the text. How can I do it (without regex, only using XMLParser)?

Comment: The XMLParser in your example only works with lxml. But `ET.tostring()` looks like ElementTree. Which are you using? Are you able to use lxml?

Comment: @daniel-haley, thanks for the comment! I use lxml, ElementTree was given just as an example of retrieving inner xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to update the [`tail`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text) property of the `<lb>` elements.

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring("<p>first_part<lb/>second_part<lb/>third_part</p>")

lb_elements = root.findall("lb")
lb_elements[0].tail = "foo"
lb_elements[1].tail = "bar"

print(etree.tostring(root, encoding="unicode"))
```

Output:

```
<p>first_part<lb/>foo<lb/>bar</p>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! One more question: if I want to strip all the inner parts of a text and I don't know precisely which tags can be inside a <p>-tag, what can I do in this case?

Comment: Try something like this: `for elem in root.iter():` followed by `elem.tail = ""`.